# How do I write a R dataframe to a csv file when every row has its own dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the rows all have their own dataframes. When I use the write.csv() function to save this dataframe into a csv file, I receive the following error:

> Error in write.table(staff, "Chiefs of Staff.csv", col.names = NA, sep = ",",  : 
>    unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

Here is the code I used

```
chiefs_of_staff<-jsonlite::fromJSON("http://www.infogo.gov.on.ca/infogo/v1/individuals/search?&keywords=chief%20of%20staff&topOrgId=0&locale=en&_=1569503878383")

 staff<-chiefs_of_staff$individuals
 write.csv(staff,'Chiefs of Staff.csv')
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what the question asks for.
The problem is complicated by the fact that some of the dataframes in `staff[[1]]` or `staff$assignments` have more than 1 row and therefore the dataframe resulting from their `rbind`ing has more than 49 rows.

Also, I have substituted underscores for the spaces in the output filename.

```
chiefs_of_staff <- jsonlite::fromJSON("http://www.infogo.gov.on.ca/infogo/v1/individuals/search?&keywords=chief%20of%20staff&topOrgId=0&locale=en&_=1569503878383")
staff <- chiefs_of_staff$individuals

assignments <- do.call(rbind, staff[[1]])
assignments$positionTitle <- gsub('<.*>', '', assignments$positionTitle)
assignments$positionTitle <- trimws(assignments$positionTitle)

l <- sapply(staff[[1]], nrow)
n <- nrow(staff[-1])
tmp <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(k){
  sapply(staff[k, -1], rep, l[k])
})
tmp <- do.call(rbind, tmp)
out <- cbind(assignments, tmp)

write.csv(out,'Chiefs_of_Staff.csv')

rm(tmp, l, n)    # final clean up
```

Comment: Why did you write staff_1_df?

Comment: @Andrew It is an earlier version of the code. I forgot to change everything to the correct final version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your json file to a format that `write.csv` can work with: calling `rbind` to your list makes a matrix writable to csv.

```
staff_csv <- do.call("rbind", staff)

write.csv(staff_csv,'Chiefs of Staff.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `assignments` column is a list of `data.frame`, there are a number of ways to handle this. Here is one:

```r
staff$assignments = as.character(staff$assignments)

 write.csv(staff,'Chiefs_of_Staff.csv')
```

That will work.